# Насколько эффективен nodejs cluster при создании MMORPG?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cluster

Коллеги, подскажите насколько эффективен на ваш взгляд nodejs модуль cluster, к примеру я хочу создать бесшовный мир как мне правильно распределить нагрузку на процессор? В качестве связи клиент-сервера служит библиотека socket.io, поднимая на каждом ядре сокет сервер, мне нужно чтобы происходил обмен между клиентами которые находяться на разных тредах, мы можем это организовать с помощью IPC канала: от воркера к мастеру, от мастера к нужному воркеру. Однако переключение контекста занимает некоторое время, сделав пару тестов выяснил что время составляет от 2-10мс. Насколько эффективен такой подход на ваш взгляд и как бы вы посоветовали организовать обмен?!

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    let start = new Array(9);
    let end = new Array(9);
    let workers = [];
    console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);
    // Fork workers.
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        let worker = cluster.fork();
        workers.push(worker);
            worker.on('message', (msg)=>{
                end[worker.id] = new Date;
                console.log(`${worker.id} затратил время`, end[worker.id]-start[worker.id]);
            });
    }

    // Дожидаемся запуска всех воркеров для более точного теста.
    setTimeout(()=>{ 
    workers.forEach((work)=>{
        start[work.id] = new Date;
            work.send('done');
        });
    },5000);


    cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
        console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
    });

} else {        
    process.on('message', (msg) => {
        console.log('Мастер шлет сообщение',msg.length);
        process.send('done');    
    });    
    console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
}
```